# In SQL how can I add my Row_Number() to my current subquery in the from clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Just as stated above I am trying to put this Row_Number() query in as a subquery in my from clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CaseID) AS RowNum
     FROM T.dbo.CompletedCase
     ) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 25
```

This is the query I am trying to put it in

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.UserId, (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [UserName], Count(c.UserId +c.CaseId+c.LineNumber) AS [CompletedCase]
FROM T.dbo.CompletedCase c join T.dbo.User u on c.UserId = u.UserID
WHERE c.PrintDateTime >= '2014-01-27 7:00' AND c.PrintDateTime <= '2014-01-27 17:00'
Group By u.FirstName, u.LastName, c.UserId
Order By [UserName]
```

I have seen how different people applied similar things to theirs but I don't get how to apply it in the from clause. If you were to explain some with answer that would be greatly appreciated! If there is a better way to do this from the SELECT clause then I am down to try it. To me it just made sense to place in FROM clause because that's where it pulls the rows from. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't exactly get what you mean. Do you want to add row_number() and limit the results of you second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do exactly the same thing (although I cannot imagine what you are trying to accomplish):

```
Select  *
From (
        SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By c.UserId) rn, c.UserId, (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [UserName], Count(c.UserId +c.CaseId+c.LineNumber) AS [CompletedCase]
        FROM T.dbo.CompletedCase c join T.dbo.User u on c.UserId = u.UserID
        WHERE c.PrintDateTime >= '2014-01-27 7:00' AND c.PrintDateTime <= '2014-01-27 17:00'
        Group By u.FirstName, u.LastName, c.UserId
    ) x
Where   x.rn Between 0 and 25
Order By [UserName]
```

Personally, I like doing this kind of thing with CTE's:

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order By c.UserId) rn
            ,c.UserId
            ,(u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [UserName]
            ,Count(c.UserId +c.CaseId+c.LineNumber) AS [CompletedCase]
    FROM T.dbo.CompletedCase c
    join T.dbo.User u
        on c.UserId = u.UserID
    WHERE c.PrintDateTime >= '2014-01-27 7:00' AND c.PrintDateTime <= '2014-01-27 17:00'
    Group By u.FirstName, u.LastName, c.UserId
)
Select  UserId
        ,UserName
        ,CompletedCase
From    cte
Where   rn Between 0 And 25
Order By [UserName]
```

But, it kind of seems like you just want the first 25 rows, so why not just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Top 25, c.UserId, (u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName) AS [UserName], Count(c.UserId +c.CaseId+c.LineNumber) AS [CompletedCase]
FROM T.dbo.CompletedCase c join T.dbo.User u on c.UserId = u.UserID
WHERE c.PrintDateTime >= '2014-01-27 7:00' AND c.PrintDateTime <= '2014-01-27 17:00'
Group By u.FirstName, u.LastName, c.UserId
Order By [UserName]
```

Comment: I need the first 25 then 26-50 that's why I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: What do you mean?  You run the query once to get the first 25, then a slightly different query to get 26-50?  Why?

Comment: Two different tables, I'm just going off instructions given to me. Yes run a query for 1-25 then 26-50. Your top one worked but the Order By didn't work. It said: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: My mistake.  Fixed the first two queries (moved order by to the outside of derived table/cte).